# how to use regular expression to change url in php

Tags: javascript, php, regex, url, path

this is my url ....where i want to change 40px to 250px ...here 40px is dynamic...how to change it in php....using regex...here is a link below

```
   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg/40px-President_Barack_Obama.jpg
```

here is the things...what i tried

```
   url="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb    /8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg/40px-President_Barack_Obama.jpg";
   var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.lastIndexOf("."));
```

so any possible soluation

Comment: Your code is JavaScript but this question is tagged PHP?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [preg-replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) like,

**PHP**

```
$url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb    /8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg/40px-President_Barack_Obama.jpg";
echo $filename = preg_replace('/\.jpg\/\d+px-/', '.jpg/250px-',$url);
```

**Javascript**

```
url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb    /8/8d/President_Barack_Obama.jpg/40px-President_Barack_Obama.jpg";
var filename = url.replace(/\.jpg\/\d+px-/, '.jpg/250px-');
alert(filename);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GyhDN/1/)